# Freezing and thawing threads in Xcode

Tags: xcode

How do I freeze and thaw threads in Xcode like I can in Visual Studio? Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail for those of us that aren't familiar with VS?

Comment: Sure. Visual Studio allows you to suspend individual threads at any point by right clicking on the thread in question and 'freezing' it. This can be invaluable when debugging code that's called by more than 1 thread at a time, as you can artificially manipulate the order of execution however you want.In my case I just want to pause a couple of threads so that I can concentrate on a single thread without frequently switching back to the other threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To suspend a thread in your running application . . .

- Pause your application’s execution,
  or wait for it to hit a breakpoint.
- In the Debug Navigator, Control-click
  the desired thread.
- In the contextual menu that appears, select Suspend Thread.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html

Comment: Thanks. I didn't make it clear in my original question that I currently use Xcode 3.2, but I like the look of Xcode 4 anyhow so will upgrade.